# how to make the closer word have higher weight in sphinx

Tags: sphinx, thinking-sphinx

all

I have  a question,  I'm using sphinx as search engine.

for example, I have these data:

```
 aaa bbb ddd cdd
 aaa ddd bbb cdd
 aaa ddd
```

and now, I'm searching aaa ddd
 I want the ese ones are all matched, and shows like that order:

```
  aaa ddd            #total matched. so shows first
  aaa ddd bbb cdd    #there is no word in aaa and ddd, so it can have high weight
  aaa bbb ddd cdd    #as there is word in aaa and ddd, so lower weight
```

in a word, I want to make the  strhing have the keyword I typed closer  have higher wight. 
is there any way to do that? thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, you should change to EXTENDED match mode to enable rankers other than MATCHANY. Looks like `SPH_RANK_SPH04` is a good point for a start. Refer to [documentation](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html).